# Binary sequence of a Image --> BMP etc

Tags: c#, image

How to get the binary sequence of a provided image in C# ?

Comment: Just plain binary or you want them nicely sorted in RGB values?

Comment: better if its shorted in RGB values :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following method gives you the byte sequence for the image saved in a given format:

```
public void ImageToBytes(Image image, ImageFormat format)
{
  var stream = new MemoryStream();
  image.Save(stream, format);
  return stream.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes("image.png");
```